# Do not use IE browser settings when using a proxy with Indy

Tags: delphi, indy

At one of our customer sites, we have a Delphi 2007 application that makes a number of HTTPS requests using indy components. All requests are made using the proxy settings the client provides.
For this to work, in IE we have to put the URL's in the trusted zones section. After a month due to security settings the trusted zones are cleared. This means we have to re-add the URLs again to make our application work.

Is there a way of bypassing IE settings or using a client side HTTP stack so we do not go through the browser to make https requests?

JD

Answer (score 3):

Indy **is** the client-side HTTP stack. It doesn't use Internet Explorer's proxy settings. It uses whatever proxy settings you've set in the `TIdHTTP` component's proxy-related properties. If you don't want to use those settings, then don't set them.

Furthermore, I'm pretty sure the "trusted zone" has nothing to do with this. It controls what Internet Explorer allows *Web pages* to do, such as run scripts and load ActiveX controls. Indy never loads, displays, or executes anything. All it does is download. Internet Explorer's settings should have no bearing on your program's ability to connect to whatever sites you wish.

Comment: We have been told by the customer to use the .net way of doing things (even though this is a delphi app) where we must use the registry ([HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
"ProxyEnable"=dword:00000001). I am not sure why they have suggested this as from your explanation TidHTTP is using the client HTTP stack and has nothing to do with Internet explorer. Any ideas what the customer is referring to? Is it possible that the Proxy is some how picking up the trusted zones URLs or using WinInet?

Comment: Just confirmed from the client that clearly our application does not work unless the URLs exist in the trusted zone. We are only using the TidHttp component.

Answer (score 1):

IE proxy settings are handled by the Internet options -> Connection -> Lan settings -> Proxy server configuration. Here you can tell which addresses should bypass a proxy server, it's not the security tab controlling that, it controls what a site is allowed to do *within IE*, and zones are used by IE only (and applications using the Web Browser control). Anyway, Indy does not use them automatically, you have to set a proxy explicitly. Do you use the web browser control?

Comment: Hi. I am looking at the code and we use TidHttp and we set proxy settings via idHttp.ProxyParams.ProxyServer etc properties. I was told by the customer that they have had to add URLs to trusted zones and then our application works. I need to do some more research into the problem.